# Undefined method error in rspec

Tags: ruby, rspec, dsl

I'm implementing a Calculator DSL that has calculate as a method with add, subtract, multiply and divide block within the the method. When I run the rspec test using 'rspec calculator_spec.rb' command, it gives me an undefined method error for 'calculate'. The error is as follows -

```
 1) Calculator Addition operation returns correct values for positive numbers
 Failure/Error: calculate do
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `calculate' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::Calculator::AdditionOperation:0x00000101d14780>
 # ./calculator_spec.rb:16:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

How can I overcome this error?

In calculator.rb -

```
class Calculator
  attr_accessor :total
  def calculate(&block)
    self.total = 0
    instance_eval(&block)
    puts total
  end

  def add(number)
    self.total += number
  end

  def subtract(number)
    self.total -= number
  end

  def multiply(number)
    self.total *= number
  end

  def divide(number)
    self.total /= number
  end
end
```

In calculator_spec.rb -

```
require './calculator'

describe 'Calculator' do

  describe "Addition operation" do
    it "returns correct values for positive numbers" do
      expect(
          calculate do
            add 2
            add 2
          end
      ).to eq(4)
    end

    it "returns correct values for negative numbers" do
      expect(
          calculate do
            add -2
            add -2
          end
      ).to eq(-4)
    end

    it "returns correct values for positive and negative numbers" do
      expect(
          calculate do
            add 2
            add 10
            add -10
          end
      ).to eq(2)
    end
  end

  describe "Mixed operations" do
    it "returns correct values when mixing all operations" do
      expect(
          calculate do
            add 2
            add -2
            subtract -2
            multiply 10
            divide 10
          end
      ).to eq(2)
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this line in your rspec:

```
describe 'Calculator' do
```

to

```
describe Calculator do
```

This will create an [implicit `subject`](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-0/docs/subject/implicit-subject) of type `Calculator`.

Besides that:

1. `calculate` always returns `nil` (which is what [`puts`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/IO.html#method-i-puts) returns):

   ```
   def calculate(&block)
     self.total = 0
     instance_eval(&block)
     total # <- no puts
   end
   ```
2. You need to call `calculate` on your `subject`, easiest fix to add a `calculate` method on your `describe` block:

   ```
   describe Calculator do
     def calculcate(&block)
       subject.calculate(&block)
     end

     describe "Addition operation" do
       # ...
   ```

Answer (score 1):

I put the code in a file called *test.rb* file :-

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

class Calculator 
  attr_accessor :total

  def calculate(&block)
    self.total = 0
    instance_eval(&block)
    total
  end

  def add(number)
    self.total += number
  end

  def subtract(number)
    self.total -= number
  end

  def multiply(number)
    self.total *= number
  end

  def divide(number)
    self.total /= number
  end
end
```

Then created the below *test_spec.rb* file :-

```
require_relative "../test.rb"


describe 'Calculator' do

  describe "Addition operation" do

    let(:ob) { Calculator.new }

    it "returns correct values for positive numbers" do
      expect(
        ob.calculate do
          add 2
          add 2                    
        end  
      ).to eq(4)
    end

    it "returns correct values for negative numbers" do
      expect(
        ob.calculate do
          add -2
          add -2
        end  
      ).to eq(-4)
    end

    it "returns correct values for positive and negative numbers" do
      expect(
        ob.calculate do
          add 2
          add 10
          add -10                    
        end  
      ).to eq(2)
    end
  end

  describe "Mixed operations" do
    let(:ob) { Calculator.new }
    it "returns correct values when mixing all operations" do
      expect(
        ob.calculate do
          add 2
          add -2
          subtract -2
          multiply 10
          divide 10                    
        end  
      ).to eq(2)
    end
  end
end
```

Now run the code as :-

```
arup@linux-wzza:~/Ruby> rspec -f documentation

Calculator
  Addition operation
    returns correct values for positive numbers
    returns correct values for negative numbers
    returns correct values for positive and negative numbers
  Mixed operations
    returns correct values when mixing all operations

Finished in 0.00197 seconds (files took 0.17971 seconds to load)
4 examples, 0 failures
```

Your code was not working, as you were calling the method `#calculate` on wrong object. You have to call this method, on the `Calculator` class instance of-course, as you have defined `Calculator#calculate`.